# Node.js box2d collisions doesn't work as i expected at zero gravity?

Tags: node.js, box2d

i have local server runs on nodejs with box2d at zero gravity. And client with cocos2d-x. When i emit some movement data from my client, server gets and applies this movement data to the objects. Problem is about collisions. When force is applied to A dynamic object(Player), A object collides with another dynamic object called B (ball) at zero gravity world. B object never floats after collision. Just moves with small amount of unit and stops suddenly. ( i tried to set linear damping to 0 and it still stops suddenly.)

Server side codes :

World.js

```
var Box2D = require('./box2d.js');
var s = require('./Server.js');

var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2,
    b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef,
    b2AABB = Box2D.Collision.b2AABB,
    b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body,
    b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef,
    b2Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture,
    b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World,
    b2MassData = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2MassData,
    b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape,
    b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape,
    b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw,
    b2MouseJointDef = Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2MouseJointDef,
    b2EdgeShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2EdgeShape;

function World(world, gravity, velocity, name, room) {

    this._room = room;
    this._name = name;
    this._world = world;
    this._gravity = gravity;
    this._velocity = velocity;
    this._gameElements = {};
    this._scale = 30;
    this._interval;

    this._size = 50;
    this._w = 900;
    this._h = 500;
    this._fps = 60;
    this._inteval;

    this._PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    this._D2R = Math.PI / 180;
    this._R2D = 180 / Math.PI;
    this._debug = false;

}

World.prototype.startEnv = function () {

    this._world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, this._gravity), true);

    this.createArea(0, 0, this._w, 5, true);
    this.createArea(0, this._h, this._w, 5, true);
    this.createArea(0, 0, 5, this._h, true);
    this.createArea(this._w, 0, 5, this._h, true);

    this.createBox(0.1,450, 250, 12, 12, false, true, 'ball','ball');
    this.createBox(1,250,250, 25, 25, false, true, 'blue','anilgulgor');
    //this.createBox(650, 250, 25, 25, false, true, 'red', username);

    this._inteval = setInterval(() => {

        this.update();

    }, 1000 / this._fps);

    this.update();

}

World.prototype.update = function () {

    this._world.Step(1 / this._fps, this._gravity, this._velocity);

    this._gameElements = this.gameStep();

    s.emitObjectsToClients(this._room.name, this._gameElements);

    console.log(this._gameElements + "name : " + this._name);

    this._world.ClearForces();

}



World.prototype.gameStep = function () {

    var elements = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var b = this._world.m_bodyList; b; b = b.m_next) {
        for (var f = b.m_fixtureList; f; f = f.m_next) {

            if (f.m_body.m_userData) {

                var x = Math.floor(f.m_body.m_xf.position.x * this._scale);
                var y = Math.floor(f.m_body.m_xf.position.y * this._scale);
                var r = Math.round(((f.m_body.m_sweep.a + this._PI2) % this._PI2) * this._R2D * 100) / 100;
                var width = f.m_body.m_userData.width;
                var height = f.m_body.m_userData.height;
                var static = f.m_body.m_userData.static;
                var type = f.m_body.m_userData.type;

                var gameObj = {

                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    r: r,
                    w: width,
                    h: height,
                    s: static,
                    t: type
                }

                elements.push(gameObj);

            }

        }
    }

    console.log(elements);

    return { elements: elements };

}

World.prototype.createBox = function (d,x, y, w2, h2, static, circle, type, username) {

    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = static ? b2Body.b2_staticBody : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = x / this._scale;
    bodyDef.position.y = y / this._scale;
    bodyDef.userData = { width: w2, height: h2, static: static, type: type, userName: username };
    bodyDef.allowSleep = false;
    bodyDef.linearDamping = 0.5;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;

    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    fixDef.density = d;
    fixDef.friction = 0.1;
    fixDef.restitution = 1;

    if (circle) {
        var circleShape = new b2CircleShape;
        circleShape.m_radius = w2 / this._scale;
        fixDef.shape = circleShape;
    } else {
        fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
        fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(w2 / this._scale, h2 / this._scale);
    }

    return this._world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);

}

World.prototype.applyForce = function (username, force) {

    for (var b = this._world.m_bodyList; b; b = b.m_next) {

        for (var f = b.m_fixtureList; f; f = f.m_next) {

            if(f.m_body.m_userData){

            if (f.m_body.m_userData.userName == username) {

                var forceVec = JSON.parse(force);

                f.m_body.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(forceVec.forceX, forceVec.forceY) , f.m_body.m_xf.position);

                //f.m_body.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(forceVec.forceX, forceVec.forceY));

                console.log(forceVec.forceX + " " + forceVec.forceY);

            }

            }

        }

    }

}

World.prototype.createArea = function (x, y, w2, h2, static) {

    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = static ? b2Body.b2_staticBody : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = x / this._scale;
    bodyDef.position.y = y / this._scale;

    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    fixDef.density = 1.5;
    fixDef.friction = 0.2;
    fixDef.restitution = 1.0;

    fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
    fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(w2 / this._scale, h2 / this._scale);

    return this._world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);

}

module.exports = World;
```

Server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const World = require('./World.js');

var usernames = [];
var roomToJoin;

//port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

//server listen
server.listen(port, () => {

    console.log(`Server is on port ${port}`);

});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //event fired when we get a new connection
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.emit('connected', `connected to the server`);

    //wait for addMe command with username parameter
    socket.on('addMe', function (username) {

        //Starting procedure of joining room
        console.log(`${username} started addMe procedure to join room`);

        //socket username is binded with client username
        socket.username = username;
        //socket room name is statically given.
        socket.room = 'room1';
        //add username to the global username list
        usernames.push(username);



        if (roomToJoin != null) {

            if (roomToJoin.length < 2) {

                //room is available to join

                //client join static room
                socket.join(socket.room, (err) => {

                    if (!err) {

                        roomToJoin = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.room];

                        roomToJoin.name = socket.room;

                        console.log(roomToJoin.length + " clients in room");

                        //join room sucessfully
                        socket.emit('connectedToRoom', `connected to the room name : ${socket.room}`);

                        //broadcast to another users in the room to warn that some user has connected
                        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('userConnectedToRoom', 'GameServer', `${username} has connected to the ${socket.room}`);

                        //room capacity is full right now
                        //we can start and emit world object positions to the clients

                        //startEmittingObjectPositionsToClients(roomToJoin);

                    }
                    else {

                        socket.emit('canNotConnectRoom', 'can not connect to the room');

                    }

                });

            }

        }
        else {

            //there is no room name socket.room

            socket.join(socket.room, (err) => {

                if (!err) {

                    roomToJoin = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.room];

                    roomToJoin.name = socket.room;

                    console.log(roomToJoin.length + " clients in room");

                    //world definition
                    var world;
                    var w = new World(world, 0, 100, `${socket.room} world`, roomToJoin);
                    // assign creator world to the roomToJoin.world
                    roomToJoin.world = w;

                    //join room sucessfully
                    socket.emit('connectedToRoom', `connected to the room name : ${socket.room}`);

                    //broadcast to another users in the room to warn that some user has connected
                    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('userConnectedToRoom', 'GameServer', `${username} has connected to the ${socket.room}`);

                    startEmittingObjectPositionsToClients(roomToJoin);

                }
                else {

                    socket.emit('canNotConnectRoom', 'can not connect to the room');

                }

            });

        }

    });

    socket.on('move', function(moveData) {

        var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.room];

        console.log(room);

        room.world.applyForce('anilgulgor', moveData);

        console.log(moveData);

    });

});



function startEmittingObjectPositionsToClients(room) {

    room.world.startEnv();

}

function emitObjectsToClients(roomName, gameElements) {

    console.log(roomName);

    io.sockets.in(roomName).emit('worldStep', gameElements);

    console.log('gönderdiiiiiiiiiiiim');

}

module.exports.emitObjectsToClients = emitObjectsToClients;
```

Everything works when i emit "move" call from my client. But collisions don't work as i expected.

Comment: i think i have found a solution which is not reliable. Just set gravity to 0.0001 on Y-axis. Impulse on objects after collisions works right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to essentially be: why is the body stopping suddenly after a collision?

This can happen because of velocity threshold setting (the `b2_velocityThreshold` value). The source code comments for this (in the base 2.3.2 Box2D C++ code) states the following about this setting:

> A velocity threshold for elastic collisions. Any collision with a relative linear velocity below this threshold will be treated as inelastic.

And in the "inelastic" case, no restitution is applied; only position resolution - which works to undo any overlapping of the two bodies but adds no velocity to them.

If this is the problem, then the velocity threshold setting can be lowered downward to zero to see less and less of bodies coming to rest. If the velocity threshold being too-high for your application is indeed the problem - and it sounds like it really is - then setting a small but non-zero gravity **is not** the proper way to solve it.

Note that Erin Cato - who is the original author of Box2D - [raises the following point](http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6131) about what one can expect with lowering the velocity threshold to zero:

> If you set the threshold to zero, non-zero restitution will cause your bodies to bounce forever.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks Louis, my problem is like the same as you mentioned above, i solve this problem by setting gravity 0.0001 on Y-Axis which is negligible and have any effect on system. But i will try to set velocity_threshold downward to zero and make you aware.